# How to slide a table down to one row in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to be fancy schmancy with my table. When I click a row, I want all the rows above and below to slide upwards, except the clicked row. So when the slide is finished, the table should have only one row, the clicked one.

I have tried several versions of selecting all rows except the one i want, but everything is hidden :/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PGKLd/3/).
You just have to select all the `tr`'s siblings and hide/animate them.
You can use jquery's built-in slide functions :

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('tr').slideUp(); 
});
```

Comment: +1 Very good solution. However, not to be locked in the slide up state, we can change it a bit and slide down as well: http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/TDUZy/

Comment: It was just a demo. But for your suggestion, you can use slideToggle : http://jsfiddle.net/TDUZy/2/